# How do I make a button respond according to any input text?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this project I am working on. Where I want the user to input a specific number like '8123' and clicks on 'Show Count', it outputs a message like 'You have 8123'. Also if the user inputs '812' and clicks on 'Show Count', it should output 'This is number 812'.

```
    /*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("CodeBlocksWindowsApp");
 char str1[5], str2[5];


HWND TextBox;


          case WM_CREATE: {

            HWND hWndTextBox   =  CreateWindow (TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT (""),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_BORDER | WM_GETTEXT,
                100, 20, 130, 20,
                hwnd,(HMENU)  NULL, NULL, NULL);


               CreateWindow (TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT ("Process "),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                200, 100, 70, 20,
                hwnd,(HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);

  if (
        SendMessage  (
        hWndTextBox  ,
        (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
        (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("8123" )));


        {

            ::MessageBox(hwnd, "You have 8123" , "Show Count",  MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

        }

        if (
        SendMessage  (
        hWndTextBox  ,
        (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
        (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("812" )));


        {

            ::MessageBox(hwnd, "This is number 812" , "Show Count",  MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

        }



   return 0;
         }
                     break;
```

My problem is that, if a user opens the application for the first time, there command comes first as in 'Your have 8123' without even any input. Worst of all, when the user inputs the numbers and clicks 'Show Count', there is no pop-up message. As if not enough, it applies to all inputs (8123, 812) the user would type in. I am told to send a 'WM_GETTEXT' then 'SendMessage' function, however, I think I did not pass them well. One more thing, I do not know how to use strcmp as an aside.
I am using Code::Blocks win32
Any help would be most appreciating.

Comment: Use `strcmp`? As an aside, why are you storing 6 characters (including the null character) in a `char[5]`? That's a buffer overflow.

Comment: @immibis thanks for answering but how do I use it as an aside? I did a google search and most people used 'strcmp' in a  console. What should I do please?